# rsync --backup-dir creates empty folders in backup dir

Tags: rsync

I have a folder structure like this:

```
.
├── bkp
├── dst
└── src
    └── folder
        └── file
```

#### I run the following command:

```
rsync -t -r -b --backup-dir /tmp/rsyncTest/bkp/ /tmp/rsyncTest/src/ /tmp/rsyncTest/dst/
```

#### My results are:

```
.
├── bkp
│   └── folder
├── dst
│   └── folder
│       └── file
└── src
    └── folder
        └── file
```

My questions are:

1. Why an empty folder is created in bkp (backup-dir)?
2. Is it possible to not create it?

Answer (score 2):

I looks like your syntax is wrong, that might be why it isn't working as expected.

#### From [`man rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

> --backup-dir=DIR

So it should look like this and this works for me:

```
rsync -tbr --backup-dir=/tmp/rsyncTest/bkp/ /tmp/rsyncTest/src/ /tmp/rsyncTest/dst/
```

The `--backup` and `--backup-dir` options only work when the files have been changed. For example, say you have 3 files in your `src` directory and you have already synced that once with this `rsync` command. If you delete one of them, and then recreate it and add a bunch of changes to the file, and then run the `rsync` command again you will notice that the old copy that was in your `dst` directory was moved to your `--backup-dir` and the new copy from your `src` directory was moved to your `dst`. If no changes are detected, nothing is put in your `bkp` directory.

Comment: I add the '=' to my command line and the problem still unchanged.

I try your command line and I have the same behavior than me.

what is your rsync version? mine is 3.1.0.

Comment: Note that this problem occurs only for the first synchronization. I mean that if I run a command (mine or yours), delte the bkp folder, re run the command, the `folder` inside `bkp` is not created and works as expected.

Comment: yes, I read your note, and I agree with it. Maybe, I miss something, but I don't see what. I am doing the **first** synchro, so there is nothing to write in the bkp, just copy all the src to dst.

Comment: Ok, why not... But 1/ what is the interest of creating an empty folder hierarchy? 2/ Where can I found some documentation about this (man seems mute)?

Comment: @Calfater, Ignore my last comment. I am unsure as to why it does it on the first run for you. I was experiencing the same thing on my older RHEL 4 box but on my mac it doesn't do that. Maybe there is some mtime change that is happening that I am not seeing that is triggering the `backup` to create that folder but not the files since they haven't been modified yet. I'm sorry I can't give a better answer than that. There isn't much documentation on the inner workings of `--backup` outside of the man page item.

Comment: thanks for your investigation and feedback, this mean that empty folders can be created in a some case, but not in other. At least, I'm not misusing/misunderstanding the man page :)

Comment: @Calfater No problem, glad to help. Looking into these kind of problems helps me expand my own knowledge base :)

Comment: `rsync` does not care whether you use `--option argument` or `--option=argument`.  This is not the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the newly created "`folder`" under `bkp` for invisible meta files (like `.DS_Store` under macOS) with `ls -a .` and exclude it with rsync `--exclude` option.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why 'folder' got created in bkp is because of the --backup-dir option. This option told rsync to designate bkp as the backup directory (i.e., it is in this folder that pre-existing files in dst folder will be moved). Just remove this option to avoid creating this folder.

Comment: I'm not sure of your response. I understand that `--backup-dir /tmp/rsyncTest/bkp/` creates a folder named `bkp` but this don't explain why a folder named `folder` is created. If I well understand the rsync man, only deleted or modified files since the previous backup should go into the bkp folder no?

Comment: Rsync mirrors the directory hierarchy from your working directory downward. If you don’t want ‘folder’ to be the parent in bkp you need to cd into the original ‘folder’ and run rsync from there.